# Can't configure Nexus as a service on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, nexus

I just installed Nexus 2.4.0-09 on CentOS 6.4. I followed the [official instructions](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/install-sect-service.html) for setting it up, including the creation of a user 'nexus' - but when I get to this step:

```
sudo service nexus start
```

... nothing happens. No error message, nothing in the log, Nexus doesn't start. It works when I run the init script as nexus instead of root; but this means that it won't start automatically when the server is rebooted, which is the whole point of this process. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you add it to chkconfig with `chkconfig --add nexus`?

Comment: What if you try `sudo /sbin/service nexus start`? Sounds silly, but I'm always having a problem with just calling `service` on CentOS, but it works fine when I prepend `/sbin`

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the runasuser in the startup script that you copied to your startup folder (/etc/init.d) and also make sure that all permissions are set up so that the nexus user can start Nexus up.

If think are still not working .. check what the logs says.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem because I was injecting RUN_AS_USER and NEXUS_HOME into my environment. Simply changing the ./bin/nexus script worked.